# Why is my nested while loop not working?

Tags: while-loop, nested-loops, robotics, robotc

I'm currently programming in RobotC, for a Vex 2.0 Cortex. I'm using encoders to make my robot go straight.

This is my code:

```
void goforwards(int time)
{
    int Tcount = 0;
    int speed1 = 40;
    int speed2 = 40;
    int difference = 10;


    motor[LM] = speed1;
    motor[RM] = speed2;
    while (Tcount < time)
    {
        nMotorEncoder[RM] = 0;
        nMotorEncoder[LM] = 0;

        while(nMotorEncoder[RM]<1000)
        {
            int REncoder = -nMotorEncoder[RM];
            int LEncoder = -nMotorEncoder[LM];

            if (LEncoder > REncoder)
            {
                motor[LM] = speed1 - difference;
                motor[RM] = speed2 + difference;
                if (motor[RM]<= 0)
                {
                    motor[RM] = 40;
                    motor[LM] = 40;
                }
            }
            if (LEncoder < REncoder)
            {
                motor[LM] = speed1 + difference;
                motor[RM] = speed2 - difference;
                if (motor[RM]<= 0)
                {
                    motor[RM] = 40;
                    motor[LM] = 40;
                }
                Tcount ++;
            }
        }
    }
}


task main()
{

    goforwards(10);
}
```

For reference, these are my Pragma settings:

```
#pragma config(I2C_Usage, I2C1, i2cSensors)
#pragma config(Sensor, dgtl2,  ,               sensorDigitalIn)
#pragma config(Sensor, dgtl7,  ,               sensorDigitalOut)
#pragma config(Sensor, I2C_1,  ,               sensorQuadEncoderOnI2CPort,    , AutoAssign )
#pragma config(Sensor, I2C_2,  ,               sensorQuadEncoderOnI2CPort,    , AutoAssign )
#pragma config(Motor,  port1,           RM,            tmotorVex393_HBridge, openLoop, reversed, encoderPort, I2C_2)
#pragma config(Motor,  port10,          LM,            tmotorVex393_HBridge, openLoop, encoderPort, I2C_1)
```

When I excecute the code, the Robot's encoder values are very close, but the robot stops moving when they reach 1000. I thought the code I wrote should return the values of the encoders back to 0 after they reach 1 thousand, and thereby the code should re-iterate in the shell loop 10 times (in this case). What have I done wrong?

Comment: RobotC is **not C**!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are updating `Tcount` at the wrong place. Do it Just at the end of the outer loop.

What you have written now makes `Tcount` increase everytime it moves ahead. By the time it reaches 1000 steps, `Tcount` is already 1000.

Your `times` is 10. So `Tcount >= time and it wont enter the outer while loop again.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the Control Variable of the inner loop (i.e. nMotorEncoder[RM]) is never updated, this means that the inner loop will iterate forever. That is, you will never go back to the body of external loop